# Android: popup button dismiss on time?

Tags: android

I have a popup button that is working fine. When i click on it it gets dismissed.
But i also want to add in a code for dismissing the popup after 5 secs if the user does not take any action on it? Is that possible?

The current code

```
final ImageButton rredButton=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.RredButton);
    rredButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater
            = (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext()      
            .getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popupright, null);
            final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(               
                    popupView,                
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,                       
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);     
            Button btnNxtScr = (Button)popupView.findViewById(R.id.nextscreen);             
            btnNxtScr.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){     
                @Override     
                public void onClick(View v) {      
                    Intent myintent1 = new Intent(colorActivity.this,colorBlueActivity.class);
                    startActivity(myintent1);
                }
            });
                    popupWindow.showAtLocation(rredButton, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                    //---                          
                    popupWindow.setFocusable(true);             
                    popupWindow.update();                          
                    //---
        }});
```

This is my updated code. What is wrong?

```
final ImageButton rredButton=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.RredButton);
    rredButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        private CountDownTimer mPopUpDismissTimer; 
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater
            = (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext()      
            .getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popupright, null);
            final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(               
                    popupView,                
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,                       
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);     

            getPopUpDismissTimer(3000, 1000);
            mPopUpDismissTimer.start(); 

        }
            private void getPopUpDismissTimer(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) { 
            mPopUpDismissTimer = new CountDownTimer(millisInFuture, countDownInterval) {


            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                Button btnNxtScr = (Button)popupView.findViewById(R.id.nextscreen);             
                btnNxtScr.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){     

                @Override     
                public void onClick(View v) {      
                    Intent myintent1 = new Intent(colorActivity.this,colorBlueActivity.class);
                    myintent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(myintent1);

                                };

        });
                popupWindow.showAtLocation(rredButton, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                //---                          
                popupWindow.setFocusable(true);             
                popupWindow.update();                          
                //---
            }

            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            }
            };
            }});
```

Comment: You can use [CountDownTimer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get a CountDownTimer like this,

private CountDownTimer mPopUpDismissTimer;  // instance variable, put in your activity class

> private void getPopUpDismissTimer(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
>       PopUpDismissTimer = new CountDownTimer(millisInFuture, countDownInterval) {

```
    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
      // put your logic for dismissing popup button
    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

    }
};
```

}

Now, invoke this Count Down Timer where you want to dismiss popup, like -

> getPopUpDismissTimer(5000, 1000);   //5000 ms is the time when you want to dismiss popup
>     mPopUpDismissTimer.start();

Comment: //you can put logic for dismissing your popup window once the window has been initialized
            View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popupright, null);
            final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
     
              getPopUpDismissTimer(5000, 1000); //5000 ms is the time when you want to dismiss popup 
                            mPopUpDismissTimer.start();

Comment: Remember to make your popup window as instance variable and dismiss the same window in your count down timer's
 @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        popupWindow.dismiss();
    }

Answer (score 0):

Try start new thread, sleep this thread for 5 seconds and then dismissdialog

Something like:

new Thread(){
    run(){
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    dismiss dialog here
    }
}.start();

Answer (score 0):

Use a [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html).

The function `postDelayed(Runnable r, long delayMillis)` or `sendMessageDelayed(Message msg, long delayMillis)` can be used.

Answer (score 0):

Add below line to your class:

```
private static final int MSG_AUTO_DISMISS = 0;
```

Then in your onClick code:

```
final ImageButton rredButton=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.RredButton);
    rredButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            //call this when displaying the dialog
            handler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(MSG_AUTO_DISMISS, 5000);

            //your own code here
        }
    }});
```

to hide the popup you have to implement a Handler to process the MSG_AUTO_DISMISS message when it comes in, so add the following code to your class:

```
private Handler handler = new Handler() {
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
        case MSG_AUTO_DISMISS:
                            //dismiss your popup here

                            handler.removeMessages(MSG_AUTO_DISMISS); //add this just in case
            break;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: can you help me with the code integrated to my example code above please? Am new to this.